# How Would I Use Cmap On A Histogram in Matplotlib with 7 values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, colormap

I am new to data visualization and MatPlotLib and I am currently working on a project visualizing the effects of Cannabis on Parkinson's Disease Dystonia. I want to use colormaps or a legend (or both) to make my data easier to read because right now everything is blue and I have only figured out how to do the x axis label.  I don't care what colors each bar is but this is what I have so far

```
plt.xlabel("Effect On Dystonia")

plt.hist(CannEffectDystonia)
```

[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnItw.png)

The legend is:

1 = Started with Cannabis

2 = Markedly Worse

3 = Mildly Worse

4 = No Effect

6 = Mildly Better

8 = Markedly Better

12 = N/A

I would like to know how to do this so I could do it on my other data exploration (I have a ton to do). Also, is there a way to take out the columns that are irrelevant? Thank you, and sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

the `hist` function returns `patches`, so your can set each patch a different color. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# make data
np.random.seed(1)
x = 4 + np.random.normal(0, 1.5, 200)

# plot:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

_, _, patches = ax.hist(x, bins=8, linewidth=0.5, edgecolor="white")

ax.set(xlim=(0, 8), xticks=np.arange(1, 8),
       ylim=(0, 56), yticks=np.linspace(0, 56, 9),
       )

colors = cm.get_cmap('Set2')
for i, rect in enumerate(patches):
    rect.set_fc(colors(i))

plt.show()
```

It will give the following figure. Hope this is what your want.

[image]